# Loopback Angular error

Tags: strongloop, loopback, angular-loopback

I can see this error when login page is loading.
"Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `find`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object (Request: GET http://api.somedomain.com/v1/Applications)

I can't guess why this error is generating now

Answer (score 0):

Can you just tell how at client side you are handling the call, because this happens when you send a request of find and you get error from server.

As Loopback Angular uses ngResource and its lb-service generated file expects an array in find and you get object in response due to some error.